# difference between ubuntu and linux mint is only desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

I want to choose a distro to start. It'll probably be debian family. So I'm checking ubuntu and linux mint. People say the difference between ubuntu and linux mint is basically the default setup and desktop environment.

So my question is does that mean it really doesn't matter which distro to choose, if I know how to customize the system, I can turn ubuntu into linux mint by installing the cinnamon desktop or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter really. By the time your done customizing and tweaking the one u choose the only time you'll remember which one you installed is when you do package updates.

Ubuntu has a larger repository and has the Unity desktop environment. That's just about it. If the only thing you are concerned about is customizing then it really doesn't matter. And if you stay within the Debian family you can easily switch.

Comment: Mint uses the Ubuntu repository for all the packages which aren't re-done by Mint, so the repositories are the same size.